# Image View Deprecated Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The content stretch property is deprecated in iOS 6.0, and I can not find an alternative that seems to work right.

Here is the code that works but deprecated in iOS 6.0:

```
UIImageView *sectionsSeparator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, separatorWidth, totalHeight)];
sectionsSeparator.image = [self imageForSectionsSeparator];
sectionsSeparator.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0, 0.25f, 1, 0.5f);
[self addSubview:sectionsSeparator];
```

I tried the code below, but the images do not line up correctly:

```
UIImageView* sectionsSeparator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, separatorWidth, totalHeight)];
[sectionsSeparator setImage:[[self imageForSectionsSeparator] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f, 0.5f)]];
[overlayView addSubview:sectionsSeparator];
```

Maybe i'm missing something, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being deprecated doesn't meant it stopped working, it just means that you should prefer an alternative but the old way is still valid.

Anyways, if you want to avoid the deprecated thing, you can create an stretchable image as it is specified in the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Edit:

The cap inset method is the opposite  of the content stretch one (it works backwards). On the content stretch you cover with a rect what you want to be stretched, here is an example:

http://j0ris.tumblr.com/post/7345178587/uiview-contentstretch

However on the **resizableImageWithCapInsets** you cover what you **DON'T** want stretched.

> During scaling or resizing of the image, areas covered by a cap are
>   not scaled or resized. Instead, the pixel area not covered by the cap
>   in each direction is tiled, left-to-right and top-to-bottom, to resize
>   the image.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:

So you the insets should be made differently.

Comment: I know what a deprecated method is, I was trying to remove the warnings.  I tried this method, but the images are not size correctly

Comment: ah, my bad, and yes ur code doesnt work like you expect it because the cap inset thing is the opposite as the content stretch, check my edit.